# python custom error message for required parameters of a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python, for a function, when a required parameter is not passed, python raises a `TypeError`. How can I customize the error message of this `TypeError`. For example:

```py
>>> def f(a):
...     print('a')
...
>>> f()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: f() missing 1 required positional argument: 'a'
```

I wish to customise the error message to include more information about the error message, like the definition of parameter. Is this doable or is their a better way to do the same?

Comment: You'd either have to make the parameter *optional* (with a default value) and do the checking and manually raising of a custom error yourself inside the function… Or you write a decorator that intercepts the `TypeError` and re-raises another custom error.

Comment: Use regular exception handling techinques?

Comment: But wouldn't the regular exception handling technique (like the first one @deceze suggested, i am assuming those are the regular ones) be bad design patterns? Because making the pattern optional, I am essentially signalling that it is okay to not provide that, plus the lsp's will not be able to detect it as required parameter?

Comment: @monte using decorator that catches the original error and rewriting it to what ever you want would not break  like that.

Comment: The problem with writing a decorator is merely that the `TypeError` does not appear to contain "a" as a single value anywhere. It just appears to contain the `arg` "f() missing 1 required positional argument: 'a'", which you'd have to regex, or take apart the function's signature and compare it to the passed `args`/`kwargs` to figure out yourself which argument was missing. While this is all doable, it seems like a lot of work for little gain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you cannot change the default exception errors in python, but you can do some tricks to get your custom message.

one idea can be use just try except:

```
try:
    f()
except TypeError as e:
    raise TypeError("Any message you like to write...")
```

second idea is to give your parameter some default option like None, and check it in your function whether it is None or not:

```
def f(a: Optional[int] = None) -> None:
    if a is None:
        raise TypeError("The message you want to raise")
    print(a)
```

and the final idea is combination of first and second idea with the decorators. You can check that by the decorator if it has the appropriate parameters for the function you defined:

```
import functools

def custom_type_error_for_functions(func):
    functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            func(*args, **kwargs)
        except TypeError as e:
            raise TypeError("The message you want to raise")
    return wrapper
```

put this decorator on top of your function and you are good to go:

```
@custom_type_error_for_functions
def f(a):
    print(a)
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I did thought about those methods, but they are not exactly what I want. Using try/except block and decorator is doable, but it wraps the entire function, the function can also throw erros which may not be Type Error. I guess there might be a way to distinguish which type of error is raised, but it sounds like a lot of work for simple gain. Thanks for your answer and time, I just wanted to check if there are any tricks which can help me achieve what i wanted to do.